# QTableView - Place pointer(highlight selection to the first row of list

Tags: c++, qt

I create own widget based on QTableView. It's something like file dialog (list). I want to act intuitively.

a) working with whole rows

b) indicator also worked with whole rows

c) using switched enter the lower level (subdirectory)

d) after run program or moving to a lower level cursor must be on the first row of the table (row 0)

And there is problem. I can not force the program to place the cursor on the first line.
I tried several methods, but none succeeded. setCurrentIndex. selectRow etc. Cursor is always somewhere else. Not highlighted, not on first line, but once it's on 10 position second on 4 position etc. It behaves unpredictably.

How can I do it?

Here my code is:

```
mFileBoxWidget::mFileBoxWidget(QWidget *parent) :
    QTableView(parent)
    ,model(new QFileSystemModel())
{
    this->setVerticalScrollBarPolicy(Qt::ScrollBarAlwaysOff);
    this->setShowGrid(false);
    this->verticalHeader()->setVisible(false);
    this->installEventFilter(this);
    model->setReadOnly(true);
    this->setModel(model);
    this->horizontalHeader()->setSectionResizeMode(0, QHeaderView::Stretch ); 
    this->setColumnWidth(1,70);
    this->setColumnWidth(2,70);
    this->setColumnWidth(3,110);
    this->setRootIndex(model->setRootPath("C://"));
    this->setSelectionMode(QAbstractItemView::SingleSelection);
    this->setSelectionBehavior(QAbstractItemView::SelectRows);
    //this->selectRow(0); //Does not work - goto first row
    //this->setCurrentIndes(Index); //Does not work - goto index x=0 y=0
}
```

Thank you with advance for all your responses.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Solved!
The problem is that the model is asynchronous. So reads the data in another thread. When I tried to set the index to the first line, still basically did not exist. The solution is, of course, to wait for loading the thread. At this point signal `directoryLoaded(QString)` is send. As a result, it is necessary to wait for the signal, and only then set index.

```
connect(myModel, SIGNAL(directoryLoaded(QString)), this, SLOT(onLoaded()));

void mFileBoxWidget::onLoaded()
{

    QModelIndex index = myModel->index(myModel->rootPath());

    this->setCurrentIndex(index.child(0, index.column()));
}
```

Comment: The solution is so simple! How I didn't think of that? It was so obvious! `directoryLoaded(QString)` is in the [Signals](http://qt-project.org/doc/qt-5.0/qtwidgets/qfilesystemmodel.html#directoryLoaded) section in the documentation.

Answer (score 0):

This is untested code, but I think something like this *should* work:

```
QModelIndex firstRow = QTableView::model()->index(0, 0);
QTableView::selectionModel()->select(firstRow,
                               QItemSelectionModel::ClearAndSelect |
                               QItemSelectionModel::Rows );
```

**EDIT:** (2013-06-19 06:12:58 UTC)

A simple (and ugly) workaround that worked so far for me is triggering a call to `m_tableView->selectRow(0)`; from a `QTimer`.

Here's the sample code:

Header:

```
#ifndef MAINWIDGET_H
#define MAINWIDGET_H

#include <QWidget>

class QTableView;
class QFileSystemModel;

class MainWidget : public QWidget
{
    Q_OBJECT

public:
    MainWidget(QWidget *parent = 0);
    ~MainWidget();

private:

    void layoutWidgets();

    QFileSystemModel *m_model;
    QTableView *m_tableView;

private slots:

    void selectFirstRow();

    // for debugging only
    void selectionChanged();
};

#endif // MAINWIDGET_H
```

Implementation:

```
#include "mainwidget.h"
#include <QTableView>
#include <QHBoxLayout>
#include <QFileSystemModel>
#include <QHeaderView>
#include <QTimer>

MainWidget::MainWidget(QWidget *parent)
: QWidget(parent)
{

    m_tableView = new QTableView(this);
    m_model = new QFileSystemModel(this);
    m_model->setReadOnly(true);

    m_tableView->setModel(m_model);

    m_tableView->setRootIndex(m_model->setRootPath(QDir::homePath()));
    m_tableView->setVerticalScrollBarPolicy(Qt::ScrollBarAlwaysOff);
    m_tableView->setShowGrid(false);
    m_tableView->verticalHeader()->setVisible(false);
    m_tableView->setColumnWidth(1,70);
    m_tableView->setColumnWidth(2,70);
    m_tableView-> setColumnWidth(3,110);
    m_tableView->setSelectionMode(QAbstractItemView::SingleSelection);
    m_tableView->setSelectionBehavior(QAbstractItemView::SelectRows);
    //m_tableView->->setSectionResizeMode(0, QHeaderView::Stretch );  // Qt 5?

    layoutWidgets();

    connect(m_tableView->selectionModel(),     SIGNAL(selectionChanged(QItemSelection,QItemSelection)), this, SLOT(selectionChanged()) );

    // This works
    QTimer::singleShot(1000, this, SLOT(selectFirstRow()));

    // Direct invocation - doesn't works
    // selectFirstRow();
}

void MainWidget::layoutWidgets()
{
    QHBoxLayout *mainLayout = new QHBoxLayout;
    mainLayout->addWidget(m_tableView);
    setLayout(mainLayout);
    setFixedSize(500,500);
}

void MainWidget::selectFirstRow()
{    
    m_tableView->selectRow(0);
}

void MainWidget::selectionChanged()
{
   qDebug("Selection changed");
}

MainWidget::~MainWidget()
{}
```

The weird thing is, if `QTimer::singleShot()` needs to be triggered with a delay of at least **~25 ms.**, otherwise it wouldn't work in my system.

Here's the alternative, subclassing `QTableView`:

```
#include "mytableview.h"
#include <QFileSystemModel>
#include <QHeaderView>
#include <QTimer>


MyTableView::MyTableView(QWidget *parent) : QTableView(parent)
{

    QFileSystemModel *myModel = new QFileSystemModel;

    setModel(myModel);
    setRootIndex(myModel->setRootPath(QDir::homePath()));


    setVerticalScrollBarPolicy(Qt::ScrollBarAlwaysOff);
    setShowGrid(false);
    verticalHeader()->setVisible(false);
    //installEventFilter(this);
    myModel->setReadOnly(true);

    //setSectionResizeMode(0, QHeaderView::Stretch );  // Qt 5

    setColumnWidth(1,70);
    setColumnWidth(2,70);
    setColumnWidth(3,110);

    setSelectionMode(QAbstractItemView::SingleSelection);
    setSelectionBehavior(QAbstractItemView::SelectRows);



    QTimer::singleShot(100, this, SLOT(selectFirstRow()));

    connect(selectionModel(), SIGNAL(selectionChanged(QItemSelection,QItemSelection)), this, SLOT(selectionChanged()));

}

void MyTableView::selectFirstRow()
{
//    qDebug("Selecting first row");
//    QModelIndex firstRow = QTableView::model()->index(0,0);

//    if(firstRow.isValid()){

//        selectionModel()->select(firstRow, QItemSelectionModel::ClearAndSelect | QItemSelectionModel::Rows  );
//    }else{
//        qDebug("Invalid index");
//    }

    selectRow(0);
}

void MyTableView::selectionChanged()
{
    qDebug("Selection changed.");
}
```

Comment: Hm.. thanks for the reply, but this is one of my dysfunctional tests :-).

If I use ->model()->index(0,0), program get error:

'((mFileBoxWidget*)this)->mFileBoxWidget::model' cannot be used as a function.

When I use ->model->index(0, 0) without (), program work, but not place cursor on the first row :-(.

Next in QT 5.0 is not function prototype for index(int row, int column). There is only index(int row, int column, const QModelIndex &parent = QModelIndex())const Despite the build is successful.

Comment: I'll try with a `QTableView` subclass as yours to see if I can replicate the problem.

Comment: Have you tried getting the model instance with `QTableView::model()`? That is, you should ask the superclass...

Comment: I need to make my own element (widget), a FileList, which will be added to the various dialogs. So that I would not have to define its properties each time. All is define in my widget and then use this in to X places. Here, it's possible problem. It seems that QTableView is activated earlier than the model. Perhaps this is the fault? If I use directly qtableview on my dialogues, everything is ok. When I use my widget, its Ko.

Comment: I noticed that after looking at your code. I understand why you want a `QTableView` subclass. That's why I deleted some irrelevant comments I made and adjusted my example. Sorry for not paying more attention at the beginning. Have you tried assigning the model **after** instantiating your `QTableView` subclass (instead of that line in the constructor)? Something like: `yourQTableViewSubclass->setModel(new QFileSystemModel)`

Comment: Last week I created a standard project with MainWindow + QTableVeiw + QFileSystemModel and the result is exactly the same :-(. So the problem is not in the declaration of view before the model. I'm beginning to think that
a) It is an error in QT5 - (QT5.1 has the same problem)
b) I use the wrong QTableView, model and SetRootPath, selectedrow.

Comment: I created a small project and.. yep, the problem you have is definitely reproducible here (Qt 4.8.4).

Comment: I even tried to encapsulate a standard `QTableView` and `QFileSystemModel` inside a `QWidget` instance. For no reason I was thinking this had something to do with subclassing `QTableView`. But now I fully realized that `1)` I'm an idiot `2)` I was wrong and `3)` the problem persists. Tomorrow I'll continue investigating about this. It seems that the misbehavior is specifically related to `QFileSystemModel`.

Comment: Hello, I have to admit that this weekend I did not have time to deal with ... Consider that I make my own FileModel and check where is a problem.

Comment: Thank you (dshulz) so much for your help. Finally the prolem was solved by Roman Došek from www.abclinuxu.cz

Comment: Thanks to you @exo! I was as intrigued as you about this issue! :-)

Answer (score 0):

You shouldn't name your member variable *model*. QTableView has function model(), the compiler thinks this->model is meant to be this->model(), therefore you get the error you mentioned.

Comment: Hm... It's truth. I renamed the model to myModel. However, even this change did not help. It seems to me that the model is not correctly connected with the QTableView. But I can not find where it.